# CasperJS Web Console Disabled

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs, javascript-injection

I am attempting to use CasperJS to perform webscraping of a certain site.

The site has provided security to insure against JavaScript Injection attacks.  As a result I am unable to use JavaScript to browse the DOM.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to go about disabling this security?

Comment: What is the site?

Comment: www.okcupid.com

Comment: Show your code, I don't see any limitations or any main functions overwritten.